# `Proxy` confusing `this[toString]` with `this[Symbol.toStringTag]`

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tostring, symbols, proxy-pattern

It only happens with `#toString`, and only when I (try to) access it through a `missingMethod`-like `trap`.

I have a factory called `createIterface` which returns a `Proxy` of an object with a large number of methods. Among this methods, I have both `#toString()` and `#id()`. `#id` returns an `interface` with the same attributes as the caller and works just fine; `#toString` should convert my `interface` to a String, but it fails.
All `interface`'s methods - including `#id` and `#toString` - are inside a `#Symbol.for("__methods")` attribute. I have made it this way for debugging's purpouses:

```
const __methods = Symbol.for("__methods");

const missingMethod = ({
    get: (obj, prop) => Reflect.has(obj, prop)
        ? Reflect.get(obj, prop)
        : Reflect.has(obj[__methods], prop)
            ? Reflect.get(obj[__methods], prop)
            : console.log(`No #${prop} property exists.`)
});

const createInterface = (...props) => new Proxy({
    ...props,
    [__methods]: {
        id: () => createInterface (...props),
        toString: () => `Interface(${ props.toString() })`
    }
}, missingMethod);

const interface = createInterface(0, 1, 2);
interface.id(); //works
interface.toString(); //error: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
```

The error throwed says it cannot (implicitly) convert Symbol to String (which is true). Thing is, `#toString` is not a Symbol. There is, however, a well-known Symbol called `#toStringTag` that defines `Object#toString()` behavior. When I implement it with the other methods my `#toString()` is ignored and `interface` returns `'[object Object]'`:

```
// see code above
const createInterface = (...props) => new Proxy({
    ...props,
    [__methods]: {
        id: () => createInterface (...props),
        toString: () => `Interface(${ props.toString() })`,
        [Symbol.toStringTag]: () => "Interface"
    }
}, missingMethod);

const interface = createInterface(0, 1, 2);
interface.id(); //works
interface.toString(); //bug: '[object Object]'
```

If I code the methods outside `__methods` it all works fine:

```
// see code above
const createInterface = (...props) => new Proxy({
    ...props,
    id: () => createInterface (...props),
    toString: () => `Interface(${ props.toString() })`
}, missingMethod);

const interface = createInterface(0, 1, 2);
const copycat = interface.id();
interface.toString() === copycat.toString(); //true
```

Other than some weird browse bug (I'm running latest Chrome, which in day of this writing is v. 71.0.3578.98) I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that accessing `interface.toString` first goes through

```
get: (obj, prop) => Reflect.has(obj, prop)
    ? Reflect.get(obj, prop)
    : Reflect.has(obj[__methods], prop)
        ...
```

You're expecting `interface.toString` to fall through the ternary here and get to the `_methods`, but `Reflect.has(obj, 'toString')` will evaluate to `true` because of `Object.prototype.toString`. Then, invoking that function on the object goes through the proxy's getter operation *again*, searching for a `#toStringTag` to call. The getter goes through all its ternaries and finds nothing, so it throws on the line

```
console.log(`No #${prop} property exists.`)
```

because `prop` is a *symbol* and cannot be concatenated.

One possibility would be to use an object that does not inherit from `Object.prototype`:

```
const obj = Object.create(null);
const createInterface = (...props) => new Proxy(
  Object.assign(obj, {
    ...props,
    [__methods]: {
      id: () => createInterface (...props),
      toString: () => `Interface(${ props.toString() })`
    }
  })
  , missingMethod
);
```

```js
const __methods = Symbol.for("__methods");

const missingMethod = ({
    get: (obj, prop) => Reflect.has(obj, prop)
        ? Reflect.get(obj, prop)
        : Reflect.has(obj[__methods], prop)
            ? Reflect.get(obj[__methods], prop)
            : console.log(`No #${prop} property exists.`)
});

    const obj = Object.create(null);
    const createInterface = (...props) => new Proxy(
      Object.assign(obj, {
        ...props,
        [__methods]: {
          id: () => createInterface (...props),
          toString: () => `Interface(${ props.toString() })`
        }
      })
      , missingMethod
    );

const interface = createInterface(0, 1, 2);
interface.id(); //works
console.log(interface.toString());
```

Another possibility would be for the getter to do a `hasOwnProperty` check instead of a `Reflect.has` check (`Reflect.has` is basically the same as `in`, and `'toString'` will be `in` almost any object):

```
get: (obj, prop) => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)
```

```js
const __methods = Symbol.for("__methods");

const missingMethod = ({
    get: (obj, prop) => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)
        ? Reflect.get(obj, prop)
        : Reflect.has(obj[__methods], prop)
            ? Reflect.get(obj[__methods], prop)
            : console.log(`No #${prop} property exists.`)
});
const createInterface = (...props) => new Proxy({
    ...props,
    [__methods]: {
        id: () => createInterface (...props),
        toString: () => `Interface(${ props.toString() })`,
    }
}, missingMethod);

const interface = createInterface(0, 1, 2);
interface.id(); //works
console.log(interface.toString());
```

A third possibility would be to make sure the property found by the initial `Reflect.has` is *not* from an `Object.prototype` method:

```
get: (obj, prop) => Reflect.has(obj, prop) && Reflect.get(obj, prop) !== Object.prototype[prop]
```

```js
const __methods = Symbol.for("__methods");

const missingMethod = ({
    get: (obj, prop) => Reflect.has(obj, prop) && Reflect.get(obj, prop) !== Object.prototype[prop]
        ? Reflect.get(obj, prop)
        : Reflect.has(obj[__methods], prop)
            ? Reflect.get(obj[__methods], prop)
            : console.log(`No #${prop} property exists.`)
});

const createInterface = (...props) => new Proxy({
    ...props,
    [__methods]: {
        id: () => createInterface (...props),
        toString: () => `Interface(${ props.toString() })`
    }
}, missingMethod);

const interface = createInterface(0, 1, 2);
interface.id(); //works
console.log(interface.toString());
```